# CommandError: Unable to serialize database

Tags: python, django

I've checked every solution but can't get it. Actually, I'm new to Django.

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission --indent 4 > project_dump.json
```

this is suggested by the instructor so I use it but whenever I enter this code I got this error [you can see the error in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2qVl.png)

Can anyone know to help me out with this?
Is there anyone who knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this error is coming because there is some language is there. I've faced the same problem because in my data there is some Japanese language. This will be solved if you remove that particular portion.